# Uniquely affect the same div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have divs that have the exact same name. On page load, I want to grab info from them like `$('.myclass').attr("title");` does, then do something to them, and make it output as the div content.

Basically like this [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2C4mQ/115/) where it grabs the title attribute and does something to it and outputs a result. Even though, they all have the same class name, they are treated as unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for this jQuery has [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
   var title = $(this).attr('title');
   // do something with it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/L2ypq1r7/

Loops over each `timeago` element, grabs the `title` and prepends to the div next to the formatted value.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2C4mQ/116/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $("abbr.timeago").timeago();

       $('.timeago').each(function() {
  var strTitle = $(this).attr('title');
   // do something with it
           if(strTitle === "2010-01-17T01:59:17Z"){ 
               $("#div1").html(strTitle);
           }
});
   });
```

Please check the JS fiddle above